# Zeta functions for flows on hyperbolic surfaces

Tags: dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-geometry, ergodic-theory

The Riemann zeta function is defined by
$$
\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^s}
$$
and can be written in the form
$$
\zeta(s)=\prod_p\frac1{1-p^{-s}},
$$
where the product is over all prime numbers $p$.

I am interest in analogous versions in the theory of dynamical systems:

**Discrete time.** For a map $f\colon X\to X$ we define a zeta function by
$$
\zeta_f(s)=\exp\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{n_k}k s^k,
$$
where $n_k$ is the number of fixed points of $f^k$. For example, if $f$ is the Markov chain $\sigma_A$ with transition matrix $A$, we have $n_k={\rm tr} (A^k)$ and so, after some computations,
$$
\zeta_f(s)=\exp\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{{\rm tr} (A^k)}k s^k=\frac1{\det(I-s A)}.
$$

**Continuous time.** For the geodesic flow on (the unit tangent bundle of) a compact surface $V$ with constant curvature $-1$ we define a zeta function by
$$
\zeta_V(s)=\prod_\gamma\frac1{1-e^{-s l(\gamma)}},
$$
where the product is over all closed geodesics $\gamma$ and where $l(\gamma)$ is the length of $\gamma$ (there are countably many closed geodesics, one in each conjugacy class of the fundamental group of $V$). Notice that $\zeta_V(s)=Z(s+1)/Z(s)$, where $Z$ is the Selberg zeta function.

> **Question 1:** Is there an alternative formula for $\zeta_V(s)$ that imitates the identity
>   $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^s}=\prod_p\frac1{1-p^{-s}}?
> $$

Of course, one can also consider the case of variable negative curvature, but this seemed to be a good starting point.

> **Question 2:** Is there an alternative formula for $\zeta_f(s)$ and an arbitrary map $f$ that could lead to a similar identity?

Comment: Not an answer, but theorem 6 [here](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/xenia/Oberseminar%202014/Oberseminar%202014.pdf) gives a presentation for the Selberg zeta function which feels kind of analogous to the [exponential] generating function sort of zeta function you have in other situations (replace the integral by a sum).

Comment: I had a look, but it seems far from what I had in mind. It would be nice to see even a specific example, say even for the modular group (noncompact quotient, but fine). It may be that transfer operators play a role.

Comment: Perhaps you might like the work of David Fried, particularly his paper "Flow equivalence, hyperbolic systems and a new zeta function for flows", 
Comment. Math. Helv. 57 (1982), no. 2, 237–259.

Comment: @Lee Mosher Thank you for pointing out the reference, I will have a careful look at it. My knowledge of the subject comes more from Ruelle-type results and further developments. I certainly should look more at the homological flavor!